# Undefined index: expires_in Google Login Api

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-oauth, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to study how to integrate Google Login on my project and it is my first time using this kind of process.

I'm already getting the data which is the given_name, family_name,email, picture and stored in the database.

But after submitting and returning on my redirected page. This error pop up..

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: expires_in

Filename: Google/Client.php

Line Number: 470
```

I check this line in Client.php. Butr I didn't do anything coming from Google Api

```
$expired = ($created
      + ($this->token['expires_in'] - 30)) < time();
```

I don't know where this expired_in coming from. I'm using CI v3. Here's my controller

```
$this->load->model('google_login_model');

  $google_client = new Google_Client();

  $google_client->setClientId(''); //Define your ClientID

  $google_client->setClientSecret(''); //Define your Client Secret Key

  $google_client->setRedirectUri(''); //Define your Redirect Uri

  $google_client->addScope('email');

  $google_client->addScope('profile');

  if(isset($_GET["code"])){
   $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);

   if(!isset($token["error"])){
    $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

    $this->session->set_userdata('access_token', $token['access_token']);

    $google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);

    $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();

    $current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if($this->google_login_model->Is_already_register($data['id'])){
     //update data
     $user_data = array(
      'first_name' => $data['given_name'],
      'last_name'  => $data['family_name'],
      'email_address' => $data['email'],
      'profile_picture'=> $data['picture'],
      'updated_at' => $current_datetime
     );

     $this->google_login_model->Update_user_data($user_data, $data['id']);
    } else {
     //insert data
     $user_data = array(
      'login_oauth_uid' => $data['id'],
      'first_name'  => $data['given_name'],
      'last_name'   => $data['family_name'],
      'email_address'  => $data['email'],
      'profile_picture' => $data['picture'],
      'created_at'  => $current_datetime
     );

     $this->google_login_model->Insert_user_data($user_data);
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $user_data);
   }
  }
```

Comment: The `fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode` method itself already sets the access token, so there should be no need to call `$google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);` yourself afterwards.

Comment: super thank you sir!!!

Comment: @CBroe Could you post your note as an answer so that the community members can use it efficiently? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
  if(isset($_GET["code"])){
   $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);

   if(!isset($token["error"])){
    $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
```

The `fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode` method itself already sets the access token, so there should be no need to call `$google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);` yourself afterwards.

(If anything, you’d probably need to pass in the full `$token` array into the second method again, so that it receives all the info, including the expiry time. But that’s really more for situations where you fetch it from the database or something.)

Answer (score 1):

For now, We can manually set the `expired_in`, because there is an issue in the `Client.php::setAccessToken($token)` function.

So let's hardcode it. As per Google default, `expired_in should be 3600`, so let's do the same.

Go to `Client.php::isAccessTokenExpired()`

```
// If the token is set to expire in the next 30 seconds.
// return ($created + ($this->token['expires_in'] - 30)) < time();

$expires_in = 3600;
return ($created + ($expires_in - 30)) < time();
```

Answer (score 0):

*vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on line 470* In this file on line 470

```
$expired = ($created
  + ($this->token['expires_in'] - 30)) < time();
```

replace above with  below :

```
    $expired = ($created) < time();
```